# mySQL UNION and LIMIT with priority for one SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables named *public* and *private* where private inherits primary keys (id) from *public* such that private.id ⊆ public

I'd like to query up to max total records from both tables matching some criteria though if an id resides in both tables, I use the row from *private* as the data is different.

I believe the naive approach would be two queries:

```
SELECT id, data, lat, lng, (function($lat,$lng)) AS distance
FROM private
WHERE lng BETWEEN $lng1 AND $lng2 
  AND lat BETWEEN $lat1 and $lat2 
HAVING distance < $dist LIMIT 0, $max;
```

$remaining = $max - $result->num_rows;

```
if(remaining > 0){

SELECT id, data, lat, lng, (function($lat,$lng)) AS distance
FROM public 
WHERE lng BETWEEN $lng1 AND $lng2 
  AND lat BETWEEN $lat1 and $lat2
HAVING distance < $dist LIMIT 0, $remaining;

}
```

Though this seems like the perfect spot for a `UNION` though I seem to be missing how to limit the second select based in the results of the first in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html).

EDITS: Removed JOINS and clarified variables.

Comment: dont know why you use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` .. you dont have `GROUP BY`

Comment: I'm not sure if that works but I would try something like putting this into the select fields of query 1 `(remaining - COUNT(public.*)) as count_fields`and then in query 2 `LIMIT count_fields`. As I said, I'm not sure if that works.

Comment: I suspect the answer lies in `ORDER BY` but `UNION` returns an ordered set. Does `ORDER BY` set the ordering of the SELECTS? If so, do I need to change my `JOIN`s to use a and b instead of tablename.column?

Comment: I'm using `HAVING` because it filters the rows after `SELECT` while `WHERE` does the filtering before (at least as I understand it. I have exactly one weeks worth of SQL experience). I'd rather do that distance calculation on a small subset of rows rather than the >100k rows.

Comment: You describe `public` and `private` on your question, but your sample doesnt use `private`, so I dont know if you make a typo or `private` isnt really relevant to the query.

Comment: Whoops, when I took out the JOINS I lost the reference to private. First query is on table private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an additional column to the result set and sort on it after the union

```
(SELECT id, data, lat, lng, (function($lat,$lng)) AS distance, 1 as OrderCol
FROM private
WHERE lng BETWEEN $lng1 AND $lng2 
  AND lat BETWEEN $lat1 and $lat2 
HAVING distance < $dist LIMIT 0, $max)
UNION
(SELECT id, data, lat, lng, (function($lat,$lng)) AS distance, 2 AS OrderCol
FROM public 
WHERE lng BETWEEN $lng1 AND $lng2 
  AND lat BETWEEN $lat1 and $lat2
HAVING distance < $dist LIMIT 0, $max) ORDER ON OrderCol;
```

The second SELECT will need an additional `JOIN` operator to exclude duplicates from private.

Comment: You need a `LIMIT $max` on the very end.

Comment: Can anyone explain the additional `JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

First asign a group identifier to each `SELECT`

Then use variables to create a row_id.

Finally filter for row_id.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90c86/9)**

```
SET @row_total = 10;

SELECT *
FROM 
   (
    SELECT distance,
           @row := @row + 1 as rn
    FROM 
        (
          SELECT `BadgeCode` as distance,
                 'private' as grp
          FROM Table1    
          UNION ALL
          SELECT `Dept`as distance,
                 'public' as grp
          FROM Table2
          LEFT JOIN Table1
                 ON Table2.`Dept` = Table1.`BadgeCode`
          WHERE Table1.`BadgeCode` IS NULL
        ) X
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row :=0) Y
    ORDER BY grp
   ) T
WHERE rn <= @row_total;
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining your code? I can't figure out how it relates to my queries? I don't need to order by distance, it's just a criteria for selection.

Comment: Then forget distance. Just order by grp. In this case I have 7 rows on each table. Assign number to each row you end bring the desire number you need.

Comment: btw, you need an aditional factor to order if you dont use distance. In my case if you select `row_total = 5` what rows will you return?? any random rows from first grp?

Comment: I can see the example was pulled from somewhere else but I'm trying to understand what you have here, what are )X )Y and )T?

Comment: Each of those is a sub query. `X` is the union. where I create an aditional field to diference between `public` and `private`.  `Y` is another subquery to create the variable `@row` and initialized in 0. `T` is the result of X + Y a table with all rows with group and id. So i just select the number I want.

Comment: I have to make and update. I now call grp `private` and `public`, and add a validation to not include `public` rows already on `private` result

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm more confused then when I started. I'll figure something else out.

Comment: Did you saw my Sql Fiddle Demo on the answer? If you didnt please check it. If you see it update to make it more similar to your problem and I will adapt it.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the schema. a query with row count of 3 and distance < 2 should result in (3,2,0),(6,1,0)(1,1,1) in no particular order.

Comment: You didnt send me the link ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101720/discussion-between-oboud-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).